# Trip/Hazard/Fall Dataset

Tags: dataset, computer-vision

I'm working on a project that involves describing/detecting 3 main situations from an image. First, if there's a trip hazard or o potential situation that could result in a fall, for example someone walking (while not paying attention) near the edge of a pool. Second if there's a fall event, and third how severe is the fall. I've done a project on fall detection before, but the URFD and Le2i Fall Dataset are a bit lacking in terms of what I need. I've made an approach in which I try to only detect as much information as I can, for example the model will detect "person", "walking", "pool", "slippers" and I used the mediapipe framework to analyze those words and it outputs: "negative" this is close but not quite what I need.

Anyone know about a data set that labels obstacles or hazards in such a way that I could predict a situation that could result in a fall?